# Why Ditto clipboard manager lost the last entry when I open a photo in Windows?

Tags: clipboard, ditto, snip-and-sketch

When I click on a photo to open it, (regardless of the location of the PC), the photo opens in the "Snip & Sketch" app and is copied to Ditto. I removed `CF_DIB` from Ditto's settings, and now the photo doesn't copy to it anymore, but my problem remains the same: when I open a photo, the last copy of Ditto comes out of my clipboard.

Then, absolutely nothing happens if I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. I have to <kbd>right click</kbd> on Ditto and resume this last copy (it's still listed in Ditto, but it's not in my clipboard anymore, it's not pasteable anymore). It's systematic and without exception, every time I click on a photo, anywhere, anytime.

Moreover, sometimes, opening a photo closes Ditto, I then have to restart the program ditto.

I have to right-click in Ditto, and click again on the last item to put it again in memory.

Why is this happening?

Ditto version is `03.22.88.00` 32 bit

Comment: Hello, not really, you need to include way more details. Which Ditto version? Where exactly do you open the photo - in which app and which picture do you click? What do you mean by "disappearing", just not being able to paste whatever was in clipboard? Since you wrote it's still on the list. Paste where?

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help. Sorry for not being specific enough, thank you for your questions.  Ditto Version is 03.22.88.00 32 bit
When I click on a photo to open it, (regardless of the location of the pc), the photo opens in the "screenshots and sketches" app and is copied to ditto. I removed "dib" from ditto's settings, and now the photo doesn't copy to it anymore, but my problem remains the same : When I open a photo, the last copy of ditto comes out of my clipboard.

Comment: Then, absolutely nothing happens if I do "ctrl V" . I have to right click on Ditto and resume this last copy (it's still listed in ditto, but it's not in my clipboard anymore, it's not pasteable anymore).
It's systematic and without exception, every time I click on a photo, anywhere, anytime.
Moreover, sometimes, opening a photo closes ditto, I then have to restart the program ditto.

Comment: You should edit the question whenever adding more details. Opening a photo in an application should not cause for it to be copied. What happens then is that it still attempts to copy it but just not in the type it's supposed to be copied in and you get a "blank" paste. Start by reverting the `CF_DIB` removal as that's pointless. Also upgrade your Ditto since it's outdated.

Comment: And yea, "Screenshots and sketches" by default copies the opened image, regardless of Ditto. What's the purpose of you opening it there? It's not a gallery app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue of Ditto. Nothing is getting lost, you just removed the `CF_DIB` type and Ditto copies it with unknown type and knowledge what to do with it, so it becomes a "blank" paste.

You should revert removal of `CF_DIB` as that could cause some crashes, especially in an older version. It's not a correct workaround that makes the app less useful.

If you want to continue opening pictures in Snip & Sketch, then you need to disable its automatic copying:

- open Snip & Sketch
- press `...` icon in top right corner and go to `Settings`

[image: ... icon]

- disable `Auto copy to clipboard` switch

But not sure why you're opening in that app regardless. There are much better choices for gallery viewing/photo editing apps. E.g. [XnViewMP](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) which is mainly a gallery but can also do basic editing.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you very much. You are my savior. Have a nice day.